# Defined a dictionary with windsor config

Tags: c#, xml, castle-windsor

I'm failed to define a `IDictionary<string,List<string>>` in windsor xml file

my class (C#):

```
public class myService 
{        
    public IDictionary<string, List<string>> Apis { get; set; }
}
```

the windsor config file:

```
<component id="myService" type="Test.Service.myService, Test.Service">
<parameters>
  <Apis>
    <dictionary>
      <entry key="api1">${api}</entry>
    </dictionary>
  </Apis>
</parameters>
</component>

<component id="api" type="System.Array, mscorlib">
  <array>
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
  </array>
</component>
```

I also tried:

```
<component id="api" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], mscorlib"> 
 <parameters>
    <collection>
      <array>
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
      </array>
    </collection>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

Can I do that with windsor config?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a strategy I use to initialize dictionaries.

- Make a custom class of your dictionary, with a copy constructor:

> ```
> public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<int, string>
> {
>     public MyDictionary(Dictionary<int, string> source)
>     {
>         foreach (var entry in source)
>         {
>             Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

- Define your component in configuration:

> ```
> <component id="DictionaryComponent" type="MyDictionary, MyAssembly">
>     <parameters>
>         <source>
>             <dictionary>
>                <entry key="2012">last year</entry>
>                <entry key="2013">this year</entry>
>             </dictionary>
>         </source>
>     </parameters>
> </component>
> ```